# Can a mod redact the edit history of this answer?

Tags: support

I think I put too much information into an answer originally (the mods know which one), and would like to redact the journal names + fields from the edit history.

Comment: Perhaps it's more effective to flag the answer for mod attention?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry for the delay, not sure how I missed this post.

This is in-progress. I had to manually go through and redact everything on all four versions of the answer. Another mod will now have to manually approve these redactions. Assuming that one of them is willing to do so, it will be done.

Let me note for the others that this is a bit of an exceptional case. We only redact answers when the existing answer "is likely to cause harm," and in cases like this (several versions, not a ton of views), we are more likely to just delete the answer altogether (perhaps with an invitation to repost it). But given that this OP has made many contributions to the site and rarely makes such requests, I think we can approve the redaction in this case.